# Create new sheet and copy text into cell

Tags: excel, vba, copy

Code have been using for years recently stopped working.

I've since upgraded to Office 365.

The code should copy the Sheet "Response", paste a copy of a cell from "Database" and name the new sheet appropriately. It continues creating new sheets in the workbook until the end of the Database list.

I get:

> Run-time error '1004': Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data.

The code runs and creates a sheet "Response4". (I've only given the database 4 lines to copy.). Debug highlights the line `ActiveSheet.Paste link:=True`.

The code works outside of my company's system. (I sent it to a friend with dummy data and it worked.)

```vb
Sub CopyCatView()

'NumResp = last row with a responses to the question held within
'  the question 'Themes' database sheet
Dim NumResp As Integer

'x for looping variable
Dim x As Integer

'y for response number variable
Dim y As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Sheets("Database").Activate

NumResp = Range("NumRowsD1").Value + 2
'NumRowsD1 is a named range comprising cell A1 on the Database sheet,
' which calculates by formula the number of comments in the database

For x = 3 To NumResp
    Sheets("Response").Copy before:=Sheets("Response")
    y = NumResp - x + 1
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Response" & y
    ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = Sheets("Database").Range("B" & x).Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("AA5:CR5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Database").Select
    Cells(x, 3).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste link:=True
    Sheets("Response" & y).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("database").Select
    Cells(x, 70).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste link:=True
    'duplicates the Response sheet as many times as there are comments (=X),
    ' numbers them Response1 to ResponseX, copies each comment into the white box
    ' on a different response sheet from Response1 to ResponseX
    'Also links through the check box reporting to the relevant row in the Database sheet
Next x
'at the end hide Sheet "Response"(deleting brings up prompts for every sheet deleted!)
Sheets("Response").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False

Sheets("Database").Activate
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: All of the select/activate... i'm sure it can work, but man is that not great in any regard.  I would 100% expect that, with cleaning up the code and qualifying all references, you will have workable code, which has appropriate longevity.

Comment: Additional point, all of your `integer` references should be `long`

Comment: @Cyril - "paste with link" is one of the few actions which *requires* ranges to be selected before the paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the "paste with link" requires ranges to be selected before pasting, I'd skip that and create a method to perform that function.

Also - use worksheet variables to reduce the repetition in your code and make for easier maintenance.

```vb
Sub CopyCatView()

    Dim NumResp As Long, x As Long, y As Long 'prefer Long over Integer
    Dim wsDB As Worksheet, wsResp As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wsDB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
    Set wsResp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Response")
    
    NumResp = wsDB.Range("NumRowsD1").Value + 2
    
    For x = 3 To NumResp
        wsResp.Copy before:=wsResp
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsResp.Index - 1) 'get a reference to the copy
        y = NumResp - x + 1
        ws.Name = "Response" & y
        ws.Range("C2").Value = wsDB.Range("B" & x).Value
        LinkRanges ws.Range("AA5:CR5"), wsDB.Cells(x, 3)
        LinkRanges ws.Range("F4"), wsDB.Cells(x, 70)
    Next x
    
    wsResp.Visible = False
        
    wsDB.Activate
    wsDB.Range("A1").Select

End Sub


'Link two ranges in the same workbook
'   rngFrom = contiguous (single-area) source range
'   rngTo = top-left cell of the destination range
Sub LinkRanges(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, nm As String
    If Not rngFrom.Parent Is rngTo.Parent Then
        nm = "'" & rngFrom.Parent.Name & "'!"
    End If
    For r = 1 To rngFrom.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To rngFrom.Columns.Count
            rngTo.Cells(r, c).Formula = "=" & nm & _
                rngFrom.Cells(r, c).Address(False, False)
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```